# When using the useState hook outside of JSX do I have to wrap it inside useEffect everytime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

So sometime I use setState inside an if statement to make sure it doesnt run unnecessarily. It works and I never get errors. I understand how sometimes useEffect can help in this situation from preventing extra re-renders but my question is, is useEffect always needed when using "useState" outside of the JSX? For example in a procedural sense like seen below when there is technically a falsy condition that prevents an infinite loops?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Item from "./Item";

// EXAMPLE CODE TO HELP UNDERSTAND THE QUESTION MORE
export default function App() {

  // I understand I do not need to check undefined as this is an example
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  if (state === undefined) {
    setState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  }

  // vs

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (state === undefined) {
  //     setState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  //   }
  // }, [state]);


  return <div className="App">{state}</div>;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. `state` is always initialised as `undefined` so your `if` is always _truthy_. You could easily simplify this to `const [state, setState] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario the if condition is checked on every render outside of the useEffect.

With useEffect the if condition will only be checked if the state was modified for that render.

Comment: Correct, the if condition is checked less with the useEffect but now we are checking the dependency value on the useEffect every re-render instead of the if statement. Is it considered the same "performance" wise or is using the useEffect or just the If statement technically better?

Comment: Using the if statement on every render will be less performace since it will be checking on something that does need to be checked, on the useEffect it's logical to check again if it has become undefined or whatever logical condition you need to perform on that state

Answer (score 0):

Using the `useState` inside `useEffect` is not required since both hooks re-renders the component, using `useState` in `useEffect` would just re-render your component **twice**.
The if statement is okay.

`const [state, setState] = useState();` sets `state` to `undefined` already - why check if the state is undefined? Its not required.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

For this case is okay.

Comment: Its just an example to help give an understanding to the question

Comment: useEffect doesnt trigger an extra re-render. Only time a re-render happens is during state / prop updates. I am more curious if letting the if statement run on every render is less performant then placing it in a useEffect. If done with a useEffect the if statement doesnt get checked after the first update but the useEffect with keep checking dependency values on re-render. So it sounds similar to just keeping the if statement